# How to use commander to generate command

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-commander

I am working on a cli tool with commander. I have this app.ts file.

```js
import { Command } from 'commander';
const program = new Command();
program.version('0.0.1');

const zoneConf = program.command('zone-conf');
const generate = zoneConf.command('generate');
generate.command('tx-commands').action(() => {
    console.log('Ran `zone-conf generate tx-commands`');
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

I expect that when I run `tsc && node app.js`, I would be able to do run a command like `zone-conf generate tx-commands`. When I do run it the output is `zsh: command not found: zone-conf`.

Is therw a step I am missing with commander in nodejs.

Comment: If you are packaging this as an npm package, read about the "bin" field in package.json. If you are not building this as a package, read about the shebang line in a script to set the interpreter. (Commander helps parse the command-line arguments, it does not install shell commands into the PATH.)

Comment: To run your command without any setup:
tsc && node app.js zone-conf generate tx-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your terminal to recognize your command you can use `npm link`. Which will create a global link for your package.

You should first build your application and then run the link command.

In your project folder run:

```
$ tsc
$ npm link
```

If this is not something you want to leave it linked, after you are done using it, you can use the `npm uninstall` to remove it:

```
$ npm uninstall -g <your-package-name>
```

If you don't want to link it globally, the comment from @shadowspawn should work:

```
tsc && node app.js zone-conf generate tx-commands
```